# bash script unexpected token in if else block?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, heredoc

I try to make a shell script to help me to deploy my api app more easy but below syntax is not valid?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]
then
  ssh root@10.6.189.9.17 << 'COMMAND'
  cd /var/www/myapp
  git pull
  npm start
  COMMAND
else
  echo "argument is not set!"
fi
```

I know this is valid

```
ssh root@10.6.189.9.17 << 'COMMAND'
  cd /var/www/myapp
  git pull
  npm start
  COMMAND
```

but not after I put them into the condition.

Comment: The `COMMAND` word to end the here-doc **must** be the **only** characters on that line -- *no whitespace allowed!* Remove the leading spaces. There is an exception where you can indent with leading tab characters, but they must be tabs not spaces: see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: @glennjackman many thanks, that's the issue! but I got argument passing problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568684/bash-script-failed-to-pass-argument-in-linux