# bash script failed to pass argument in linux

Tags: linux, bash, macos, heredoc

I have a bash script, the file name is deploy.sh so in my terminal I do

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]
then
  ssh root@101.181.42.10 << 'COMMAND'
    cd /var/www/myApp
    git pull
    npm i
    pm2 kill
    pm2 start pm2.json --env $1
COMMAND
else
  echo "argument is not set!"
fi
```

but I got this error `error: option`--env ' argument missing` which means $1 is not set, I wonder why, I tried this in my terminal

```
. deploy staging
```

then my bash I have

```
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
  ssh root@101.181.42.10 << 'COMMAND'
    echo $1
COMMAND
else
  echo "argument is not set!"
fi
```

I can see 'staging' been print. Am I concat the argument wrongly in my command?

Comment: Don't use string delimitator on inline document: `<<COMMAND` instead of `<<'COMMAND'`.

Comment: Read bash's man page section `Here Documents`.

Comment: F. Hauri is correct: when you single-quote the here "word", you effectively single quote the entire here-doc, so your variables will not be expanded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using variables inside a bash heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937792/1255289)

Comment: Both these examples should be failing, and they do on my machine. Could you copy-paste your second example into a new file and run it as described to double check that you are indeed seeing `staging` with that exact snippet?

Comment: @F.Hauri answered the question, that's the only mistake.